# Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'

Tags: ionic-framework

i am facing this issue when add firebase dynamic links in ios android working fine
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '5.15.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '5.15.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 7.4.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 7.0.0'

Comment: Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31 Error output: